# Get the highest value in google firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase

How can I get the highest object value in google firebase?

This is the initial script but I do not have an idea how to get the highest value and incorporate this on my script.

see

[image]

```
resultsStore.child("statement"+(i+1)).once('value', function(snapshot){

   var dataObj = snapshot.value();
   var answers = Object.keys(dataObj);
   var count = Object.values(dataObj);

});
```

HTML structure:

```
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="5" name="group" /><label>Strongly agree </label></p><br>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="4" name="group" /><label>Somewhat agree </label></p><br>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="3" name="group" /><label>Neither agree or disagree</label></p><br>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="2" name="group" /><label>Somewhat disagree</label></p><br>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="1" name="group" /><label>Strongly disagree </label></p><br>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="0" name="group" /><label>Don’t know / Can’t say</label>
```

Comment: You can order by the child values and limit the response to 1.If you could post your DB schema, I can help you in a better way.

Comment: here you go https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwF33.png

Comment: Are you asking about highest value amongst the listed child nodes? i.e. the highest value of:  don't know->Can't say vs Neither Agree or disagree vs Somewhat Agree etc or are you asking for the highest value comparing all of the statements by the value of the child node Somewhat agree?

Comment: @Jay sorry I forgot to include the HTML structure. I edited and add the html. But what I need to get in firebase is the highest count of the responses. Like what I attached above. Somewhat agree has the most responses

Comment: So do you want the highest number of the child nodes within statement1? i.e. you want 26 because Strongly disagree is 2 and the highest is Somewhat agree which is 26?

Answer (score 3):

You can try 
`firebase.database()
    .ref('results/statement1/DontKnow')
    .orderByValue()
    .limitToLast(1)`

Comment: I think you want the ref with `DontKnow`. You'll also want `limitToLast(1)`, since Firebase queries are order *ascending*.